# Execute javascript code straight before page submit

Tags: javascript

There are a few similar questions to this but none quite the same.

I want to know if there is an event that can be used to execute some JS before a page is submitting (i.e. POSTed).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are working with the form, you can use **onsubmit** event.

Using jQuery you can do that with

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: This method never works for me. The form just submits as usual.

Comment: @americanknight you need to use the preventDefault method to stop the button action.

 $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
   e. preventDefault();
});

Comment: I use $('form').submit(function () {
            //code
        }); because there is no form id in my case

Answer (score 59):

Something like this?

```
<form onsubmit="do_something()">

function do_something(){
   // Do your stuff here
}
```

If you put `return` like the code below, you can prevent the form submission by returning false from the `do_something()` function.

```
<form onsubmit="return do_something()">

function do_something(){
   // Do your stuff here
   return true; // submit the form

   return false; // don't submit the form
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can bind an event handler to the `submit` event (following code assumes you have an `id` on your `form`):

```
document.getElementById("someForm").onsubmit = function() {
    //Do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use on the `onsubmit` event on your form.

In pure HTML (without jQuery), you can use:

```
<form onSubmit="mySubmitFunction()">
   ...
</form>
```

More details here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @askepott , thanks for bringing this to my attention the link is now fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code will abort the submission from the window level, which will not submit the form.

```
window.onsubmit = function() { alert('aborting submit'); return false; };
```

Tested with IE11, so it should work for some legacy applications without jQuery.