# Sleep() doesn't delay on form action

Tags: php

When I click on the submit button, I want a delay of 3 seconds and then a redirect.
My form will redirect to an other PHP site.

My code:

```
<button
    class="button actionContinue scTrack:unifiedlogin-login-submit"
    type="submit"
    id="btnLogin"
    name="btnLogin"
    value="Login"
    pa-marked="1">
    Einloggen
</button>
</div></div>
<input type="hidden" name="" value="">
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        sleep(3);
        // AND NOW action;
    }
?>
```

Example

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        sleep(3);
        // AND NOW action;

        redirect('Location:next page.php');     
    }
?>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: if you put an action after the sleep, does it wait for 3 seconds before performing the action? Like a simple echo. Try increasing it for testing purposes, like to 10 seconds, as page load times might be slow. Also, be careful adding sleep to code. It may be useful in some cases, but we tend to strive for fast page load times without delays.

Comment: Yes right thats i want

Comment: change sleep to `10` and after it put `echo "whatever";`. what happens?

Comment: Nothing, instantly redirect

Comment: Can you check if my example code i have posted is correct? also i have deleted in form action="" the page

Comment: comment out or remove the redirect as it makes testing basic things harder. on your check for if `$_POST['submit']` is set, add an else and echo "not set".

Comment: Not any results..

Comment: it does nothing at all? it will echo one thing or the other, logic dictates it has to#

Comment: in your `<?php` area have this `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {echo "it is set"; } else { echo "it is NOT set";}` and nothing else (dont redirect or sleep)

Comment: I get the it is NOT set message under the button after i visit my page

Comment: PHP is server side script with everything run by the time it gets to the browser. Your script is telling the server to wait 3 seconds and then continue, then once everything is done it will be pushed to the browser where it just sees the redirect and redirects. If you change it to sleep for 10 seconds it will take longer for the server to process the script but it will still redirect straight away. I would say that your options are to either use a JavaScript redirect (`window.location.href = '...'`) with a setTimeout or a meta tag (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=...." />`).

Comment: You are running `sleep` on server-side. You must run it on client-side (Javascript). More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133775/161640

Answer (score 1):

So the basic debugging in the comments shows that the `$_POST['submit']` value which you expected to be there is actually not present. This is why your sleep is not working as the condition in your `IF` is not true.

So the next step is debug why you don't have that POST data. Which is because you don't have that as a form element. You will have `btnLogin` because that is the name you provided in your button.

```
name="btnLogin"
```

You can either test for the name you currently have:

```
isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
```

Or change the name in your button to `Submit`:

```
<button
    class="button actionContinue scTrack:unifiedlogin-login-submit"
    type="submit"
    id="btnLogin"
    name="Submit"
    value="Login"
    pa-marked="1">
    Einloggen
</button>
```

---

EDIT: Try this as per your request in comments:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
    {
        sleep(3);
        redirect('Location:next page.php');     
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes thanks also without results. if i just use sleep without anything the page delay on visit

Comment: The page delays on visit? What do you want it to do? `sleep()` will literally halt the script entirely, nothing will happen for those 3 (or whatever) seconds.

Comment: I want sleep if first after i click my submit button and then redirect

Comment: I've updated my answer. If that doesn't work you'll have to explain in detail what happens.

Comment: The best i dont know what happens.. Nothing really nothing makes an differant, i think the" if (isset($_POST['btnLogin']))" is the Problem? Can i write it on other way?

Comment: At this stage I don't know what you need, or what happens in your code. The code I have given you works and is tested. If you are having issues still then you need to explain clearly what the issue is. Also consider that you might be under confusion as to what to expect from the code. The only time anything will happen is when you click the button. You need to have a form for this to work, but given you have a closing form tag I presumed you had this already. If that's not the case then we need more code. Basically, either way we need more info to be able to help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, maybe the Problem is that i run the script on Localhost with wamp server?

Comment: @anit234 No thats not the issue